# Make a hugo static website site navigate correctly when browsing from the local file system

Tags: hugo

I understand that the normal workflow with hugo is to generate a static site using the "hugo" command, and then [deploy your site by copying the public/ directory to your production web server.](https://gohugo.io/getting-started/usage/) I don't want to do that: I just want the html files in the public/ directory to display correctly, and have links that work, when I open them in my web browser. I do not want to run the "hugo server" command.

Specifically, the links that are generated are all missing "index.html" at the end.

For example, a link to the About page will be:
`file:///C:/Users/myusername/Documents/HugoTesting/quickstart/public/about/` which will open a view of that directory when I click on it. But it will display the web page properly if I can change the link  to: `.../public/about/index.html`

How can I make that change throughout my site? I already set "relativeUrl" to true in my config file, as it says to do here:
https://gohugo.io/content-management/urls/ as it was necessary to get my index page to display properly. The documentation there says this helps to " make your site browsable from a local file system" so I know it must be possible.

I've tried [using permalinks](https://gohugo.io/content-management/urls/#permalinks-configuration-example) and [using frontmatter](https://gohugo.io/content-management/urls/#set-url-in-front-matter) to try and add "index.html" to all of my links, but hugo is adding an extra '/' to whatever I specify using permalinks, and while the "url" tag in the frontmatter works, it's not feasible for me to do for every url in every page.

Comment: You're running a mini web server - Not sure what the issue is... if you can get to the page via web browsing. Good job, that's how a web server works. I guess, Why would you browse to the public folder?

Comment: I don't want to run a web server. When I open the index.html that hugo generates in the "public" directory, I want the links on that page to work. Those links point to other locations in the public directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think ugly URLs configuration in Hugo might help you with this, (e.g., example.com/urls.html).

Set `uglyurls = true` or `uglyurls: true` in your site’s config.toml or config.yaml, respectively.

Comment: This fixes almost all of my links! Some of them on the homepage of the [quickstart example site](https://gohugo.io/getting-started/quick-start/) are still broken: for example, the link to "file:///C:/Users/.../quickstart/public/" with the title "My blog" is still missing "/index.html" on the end. (Or perhaps it should be post.html? For some reason, hugo is generating two very similar html files.)

Comment: Ah, interesting! I think in that case you could directly link to `/index.html` instead of `/` and it should work. Give it a try and let me know how it works.

Comment: I ended up going to a Hugo forum for help, and I learned that while this route is possible, it's not recommended: 
https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/make-your-site-browsable-from-a-local-file-system/35098